# scala 2.8 implict java collections conversions

Tags: scala, type-conversion, scala-2.8

I'm trying to convert a project over to scala 2.8 from 2.7 and I've run into some difficulty in the code that interacts with Java. Below is a slightly convoluted piece of sample code displaying the problem. Essentially I have class with a member variable of type `mutable.Map[K,V]` and I can't find a way to pass that through to a method that expects a `java.util.Map[K,V]`. Any help would be great.

```
scala> import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

scala> class A[K,V](m : collection.mutable.Map[K,V]) { 
     | def asJava : java.util.Map[K,V] = m
     | }

<console>:9: error: could not find implicit value for parameter ma: scala.reflect.ClassManifest[K]
       def asJava : java.util.Map[K,V] = m
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know why you are trying to repeat the conversion from `JavaConversions`, but i think you can do it with adding the implicit parameter `ma` requested:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
class A[K,V](m : collection.mutable.Map[K,V]) {
 def asJava(implicit ma:ClassManifest[K]) : java.util.Map[K,V] = m
}
```

---

*From console*

```
scala> import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
class A[K,V](m : collection.mutable.Map[K,V]) {
 def asJava(implicit ma:ClassManifest[K]) : java.util.Map[K,V] = m
}
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

scala>
defined class A

scala> val map=scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[Int, Int]()
map: scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[Int,Int] = Map()

scala> map += 0->1
res3: map.type = Map(0 -> 1)

scala> val a=new A(map)
a: A[Int,Int] = A@761635

scala> a.asJava
res4: java.util.Map[Int,Int] = {0=1}
```

Comment: Thanks Patrick. That worked perfectly. I'm not trying to repeat the conversions, that example was just the easiest way to show the problem I was having.

Answer (score 5):

Easily solvable:

```
class A[K : ClassManifest,V](m : collection.mutable.Map[K,V]) {
  def asJava : java.util.Map[K,V] = m
}
```

Though, as mentioned, it begs the question as to why you are bothering to replicate this method, which you could call directly from `JavaConversions`, or even use it implicitly. You might have good reasons for it, of course, or you might have done it just to get around how conversions worked on Scala 2.7.